# Adding an include file to wordpress/woocomerce site to show on product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to figure out what file I need to add custom code to, so content shows specifically on the pages I am wanting.

I am wanting the custom content to appear on these types of pages:

https://www.getmowers.com/shop-mowers/

and then when you click on the category:

https://www.getmowers.com/product-category/used-mowers/

This is a Wordpress site with Woocommerce. The theme is stefan.

Does anyone know what file this would be?

Comment: For shop page you need to override **woocommerce.php** in your theme and for category page, I believe **content-product_cat** should be the correct template to be overridden.

Comment: I think you can achieve success using **archive-product.php**

Comment: @FahamShaikh Where is `archive-product.php`?

Comment: Also, I don't have the woocommerce file in my theme. It is outside of the theme folder and is in the `plugins` then `woocomerce` folder.

Comment: I believe the file is `content-product`, but whenever I add something, the file loops through it and the content shows up a million times. What is the file that contains the `content-product` file?

Answer (score 0):

The sub-folder `loop` had a file `pagination` within it that did the trick.